# A place to request for icons for Stack Overflow communites

Tags: feature-request, images

This community (Meta Stack Exchange) has a nice icon:

[image: icon]

Stack Overflow also has a nice icon:

[image: icon]

However, take a site like Board & Card games. Their icon is a default:

[image: icon]

That is very bland, and the icon for most communities. Stack Exchange could crowd-source their icons, as in asking the community to make icons and then use them. For example, I could suggest this image:

[image: icon]

(Perma-links: [Large (512 x 512)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADS40.png), [Stack Exchange iPad size (158 x 158)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW272.png))

But, of course, this would get upvoted/downvoted by the community (and probably won't be used.)
So, I think this is a valid way to get icons for a Stack Overflow community, and will probably be a bit of fun for a few months.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A customized icon is a *privilege* for the site and its community awarded for graduating in the network. If they want one, they have to work for it and make their community succeed.

All beta sites use a standard bubble icon with initials on it (or with a very simple logo if there's any good one) during the beta phase, which matches the beta theme they also use. When a site graduates to a full site, Stack Exchange itself designs a custom theme for the site which includes a customized icon.

Comment: I didn't see that written in the help centre. Thank you for the answer